# Does the existence of an almost complex structure solely depend on the topology of the manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

To be precise, let $M$ and $N$ be two 2n-dimensional smooth, closed manifolds that are homeomorphic. If $M$ admits an almost complex structure, can we deduce that $N$ also admits an almost complex structure?

Comment: In dimensions $\leq 8$, we have a complete set of obstructions to the existence of an almost complex structure, and one can check that they don't depend on the smooth structure. I believe the answer is not known in general, but I would be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: do you happen to know if there homotopy equivalent closed smooth manifolds one of which is almost complex and the other one isn't?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, Kahn has shown that for every $k\geq1$ there exist a pair of smooth, closed, connected, oriented $8k$-manifolds, which are oriented homotopy equivalent, but only one of which admits an almost complex structure. See Corollary 6 of [Obstructions to extending almost X-structures](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-13/issue-2/Obstructions-to-extending-almost-X-structures/10.1215/ijm/1334250797.full).

Comment: On the first page of Kahn's paper he states that $CP^2$ with the opposite orientation admits no almost complex structure. This answers the original question. Of course, one can then ask a modified question with "homeomorphism" replaced by "orientation-preserving homeomorphism".